# Nuxt 3 Dynamic page route creation problem

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I generated my nuxt 3 project. The site opens and I can navigate between pages. But when I enter the inner pages and refresh with F5, it gives a 404 error.

It doesn't matter if it's /contact or /user/2, they're all the same. First, I set up .htaccess. It redirects to the homepage instead of 404. But I haven't been able to solve the problem. The problem is solved when I create generate -> routes in nuxt.config.ts, but here I want to add all pages dynamically. I get an error when I use a function. How can I solve this?

This code gives an error.
Error : TS2322: Type '() => Promise ' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Examples I tried but got errors

```js
routes: function () {
            return axios.get(
                'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
            )
                .then((response) => {
                    let users = response.data.map((user) => {
                        return {
                            route: '/users/' + user.id,
                            payload: user
                        }
                    });
                    return ['/some-other-dynamic-route-or-array-of-routes/', ...users]
                });
        }



generate: {
    routes: async () => {
      const dynamicRoutes = await fetchDynamicRoutes(); // Veritabanından dinamik rotaları getirme

      // Veritabanından alınan dinamik rotaları işleyin ve bir dizi olarak döndürün
      const routes: { route: string, payload?: any }[] = dynamicRoutes.map((item: any) => ({
        route: `/dynamic/${item.id}`, // Her dinamik sayfa için benzersiz bir URL oluşturun
        payload: item, // İsteğe bağlı: Sayfa bileşenine veri geçirme
      }));

      return routes;
    },
  },
});
```

This works. But '/homes/{slug}' here is dynamic.

```js
routes: [
            '/reservation/mango-suit',
            '/homes/mango-suit'
        ]
```